# Distribution of first exit time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be standard one dimensional Brownian motion and $\tau = \inf\{s : B_s \notin (a,b) \}$ where $a<0<b$ are real numbers.

What is the distribution of $\tau$?

I know that for **hitting** times $\tau_a = \inf \{s : B_s =a \}$ the distribution can be calculated with the reflection principle. And clearly $ \tau = \tau_a \wedge \tau_b$. So how can I continue?

Comment: See this [duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2322830/36150). Another approach: The joint law of the running supremum $\sup_{s \leq t} B_s$ and infimum $\inf_{s \leq t} B_s$ is known and this allows you to write down some expression for the density of $\tau$.

Comment: @saz Ok, so I could write $P(\tau > t)=P(\sup_{s \leq t} B_s <b, \inf_{s \leq t} B_s >a)$. Is there any standard literature where I can find this joint law?

Comment: E.g. in the book on Brownian motion by Schilling & Partzsch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Laplace transform of the density $f$ of $\tau$ is given by
$$
f^*(\lambda)\equiv \mathcal{L}\{f\}(\lambda)=\mathsf{E}e^{-\lambda \tau}=\frac{\cosh((b+a)\sqrt{\lambda/2})}{\cosh((b-a)\sqrt{\lambda/2})}, \quad\lambda>0
$$
(see, for example, Exercise 7.5.3 in [Durrett's book](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)). Then one needs to calculate the inverse Laplace transform to get $f$. For $t>0$,
$$
f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{f^*\}(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\varphi_k(a,b)}{\sqrt{2\pi}t^{3/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(\varphi_k(a,b))^2}{2t}\right\},
$$
where
$$
\varphi_k(a,b):=\frac{b+a}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}(1+2k).
$$

Comment: Isn't the inverse Laplace transform usually a complex integral? (Mellin's inverse formula) How do you get the relatively neat looking sum?

Comment: @ThomasAhle I found this result on page 282 (18) in [this book](https://blasingame.engr.tamu.edu/z_zCourse_Archive/P620_14C/P620_14C_zReference/PDF_Txt_RbrtKfmn_Lap_Trn.pdf).